# Laravel Eloquent relationship efficency

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

When I declare a relationship in a model, for example:

```
class Post extends Model
{
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
    }
}
```

Are comments retrieved from the database the moment I retrieve the Post instance or the moment I write

```
$post->comments;
```

?

Comment: This is an excellent question and a very important one to understand when learning how OOP works! Please see my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers so far solve this problem in pieces, but not very clearly so allow me to help.  To answer your question bluntly, creating a `Post` instance **does not** also load associated `comments`.

Here is why:

When you define an Eloquent relationship, you are basically attaching a whole new 'query' method to your object and so it won't actually be executed unless you call it.

As a simple example we have `Car`:

```
class Car {

    public $color;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->color = 'blue';  
    }

    public function makeRed() {
        $this->color = 'red';
        return $this;
    }
}
```

In this example, the instantiated `Car` will only have one property, `color`.  This car will be blue **unless** you call the `makeRed()` method and change it.  It does not compute both options simultaneously expecting that you may decide to change it's color.

So to relate that back to the Eloquent relationship, the `comments` method returns a relationship object, but only if the method is called on the `Post` object.  Up until that point, your Post object will not automatically call it's own methods.  Basically, don't worry about an object becoming large with a ton of methods as these methods only contribute to object size significantly if they are actually called.

If you wish for `comments` to be loaded with your `Post` immediately, eager loading the initial query will allow this by:

```
$post = Post::with('comments')->findOrFail('post_id');
```

Otherwise, the following would give you the comments for a given post:

```
$post = Post::findOrFail('post_id');
$post->comments;
```

Please see the Laravel documentation on [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) for more information.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

The answer its simple:

```
   $post->comments() returns the relationship object

   $post->comments returns the result of the relationship
```

So the moment you do `$post->comments` that means fetch relationship and execute query, therfore returns relational database results.

Answer (score 2):

They are retrieved when you ask for it, i.e `$post->comments`. If you want to eager load them, you can write `Post::with('comments')->get()`. Check out [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading). It explains eager loading and the N+1 problem.

From the docs:

> When accessing Eloquent relationships as properties, the relationship data is "lazy loaded". This means the relationship data is not actually loaded until you first access the property. However, Eloquent can "eager load" relationships at the time you query the parent model. Eager loading alleviates the N + 1 query problem.

Comment: I think you need to go and read the documentations before trying to answer on so, the question it's not about the n+1 which clearly he is not experiencing that issue as he is accessing the comments as attribute or partially eager loading. That means the query in that way its more 'efficent' than actually a full eagerloading. It all breaks down on which way op wants to make use of it.

Comment: It clearly asks about query efficiency. It is in the title of the question. He asks if the relationship is loaded on model retrieval or when accessed via property. The answer is clear. They are lazy loaded, but if you want to eager load, you can do as well.